# How to switch into a specific app in Lightning Experience from a link?

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-apps

In Classic, the "Tab Set Id" (tsid) could be included in a link to switch the selected app. (Yes this is URL hacking.)

It looks like in Lightning Experience such switching is not possible:

- [Deep Link (Direct Link) to a Salesforce Lightning App](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000ECd3QAG)
- [Deep Link (Direct Link) to Salesforce App (i.e. Services, Sales, Marketing...etc)](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000e2y0QAA)

Personally, I agree with this quote from the second link:

> I am not sure why Salesforce doesn't provide a way to Deep Link to a
>   Lightning App. Seems like a very basic feature, that most PaaS, SaaS
>   platforms provide.

and would be delighted to find that there is in fact a way to do this. Is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to switch apps using a url:

To switch to a standard app: https://[domain].my.salesforce.com/lightning/app/standard__Sales

To switch to a custom app:
https://[domain].my.salesforce.com/lightning/app/c__[app developer name]

Bonus! You can also deeplink to an app and a record:
https://[domain].my.salesforce.com/lightning/app/c__[appdevelopername]/r/Account/[recordid]/view